# Mean and variance of words pronounced

Tags: scripting, math

I'm working on linguistics and am trying to calculate the average sentence length and how much this average varies.  I worked to leave always one sentence per line

For instance:

> La dernière fois qu'on, la dernière fois on l'a pas fait
>
> Ouai

Those are 14 words, a mean of 7 per sentence and a variance of
(7-13)^2/2 + 36/2 = 36, which is really high.

[image]

I used the `gedit`command and copied an past my work: for instance the begining of the file `phrasesAntoine`:

> Allumlalum...Elal...
>
> Allume  sinon sinon non, mais au moins pour vérifier.
>
> Si si
>
> La dernière fois qu'on, la dernière fois on l'a pas fait
>
> Les amis j'vous présente Bob, Bob le gri-gri.
>
> Salut les amis, Hey
>
> Tiens, on te passe le grigri, celui qui a le grigri a le droit de parler
>
> C'est lui qui a la parole
>
> Il a dû…

I'm looking for a script that would be able to place every line of a text file in an array in order to know their length and find the mean and the variance or any kind of idea that would allow me to find this variance.
Actually "Qu'est-ce que c'est" is 6 words each one separated by a **blank** or **'** or **-**

I first thought about:

```
file wc -l >stat
```

To get this information for each line, but I'm rather new to scripting... I then thought of creating another file named `calculator` taking the stats as an argument that is the variable `$file`:

```
file
int number_of_phrases = $file wc -l;
int mean = /*number of words divided by number of phrases*/
int sum = 0;
int variance =0 ;
for i=0 to number_of_phrases{
    /* here is the calculation of xi-m
    sum = sum + (number of words at line i divided - mean)^2*/
}
variance = sum/number_of_phrase
```

That is my best guess. **Do you have a better idea?**

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain exactly what data you need to extract from your file. Also, show us an example of this file. Will there always be one sentence per line? Can there be multiline sentences? Will this be a UTF8 file? How many "words" is "Qu'est-ce que c'est"? `wc` will count 3, do you consider it 3? Or perhaps 6? Or 4? How about "I'm running aren't I"? Is that 6 words or 5 or 4? The whole concept of "words" is not very well defined as I'm sure you know. We're *nix geeks, not linguists, so please [edit] your question and clarify exactly what you need.

Comment: So words are defined either by whitespace or by `'` or by `-`? So you consider `gri-gri` to be two words but `grigri` to be one? How about something like `John's`, is that one word or two? It would be considered one in English. Or something like "porte-clefs" which would be considered one word in French?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Perl](https://www.perl.org/) is probably the best language for this kind of work.  Perl's primary author, [Larry Wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Wall), is both a unix programmer and a linguist, and the language strongly reflects his interest in linguistics.  There are numerous [`perl` modules](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=linguistics&mode=all) for language processing as well as simple text processing.

For example, [Lingua::Sentence](http://search.cpan.org/~achimru/Lingua-Sentence-1.05/lib/Lingua/Sentence.pm) which is a `perl` module for splitting paragraphs into sentences.  And numerous other `Lingua::` modules.  In fact, `Lingua::Sentence` and [related modules](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Lingua&mode=all) were written for a task very similar to what you are doing now, statistical analysis of texts (in this case, the [Europarl corpus](http://www.statmt.org/europarl), text extracted from the proceedings of the European Parliament)

You could, for example, use `Lingua::Sentence` to split each paragraph into sentences, count the number of words in each sentence, store that count in an array, and then perform whatever statistical analyses you need on the array.

Perl also has numerous modules for statistical analysis, which you can also find at [CPAN](http://wwww.cpan.org/) (the Comprehensive Perl Archive Network) or you could output the raw data to a file and process it with [R](https://www.r-project.org/) or some other stats tool.